# RLoginでRAW形式で取得したログをテキスト形式へ変換する方法はある？

Tags: ssh

**RLogin過去ログを見たら、(デフォルトの)RAW形式で取得されていました。**
下記のような感じで見づらいので、このログをテキスト形式へ変換したいのですが、可能ですか？

```
include fastcgi_params;
[7mdefault.conf[27m[K
[K [KESCESC[KOO[KAA
[K
```

既存のRAWログをテキスト形式のログへ置換する方法があれば知りたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RLoginのRAW形式のログは、制御コード(文字コードが0x00～0x1F）を含むテキスト(文字列)です。

RLoginの初期設定では文字コードがUTF-8のはずですから、文字コードがUTF-8の文字として表示する機能を持つバイナリエディタ(xedit等フリーソフトが公開されています）でログを開いてみると中身が判ると思います。

ログをどのようなテキスト形式に変換したいのか判りませんが、簡単なのは制御コードを削除する方法です。
操作手順は、ログファイルをバイナリエディタで開いて、0x00～0x1Fのコードをスペース（文字コード　0x20)に置換して別名で保存。保存されたファイルを普通のテキストエディタで開いて、連続するスペースを１つのスペースに置換して保存。

ログに漢字等の他バイトコード文字を含む場合、制御コードを削除してしまうと文字化けが生じる可能性がありますから、どんな変換が可能なのかを元のログをバイナリエディタで眺める段階で判断してください。